# Renaming Title column in list definition

Tags: list

I have a list definition and I want to rename the title column to something else, I couldn't find anybody on the internet describing how to do so.

Comment: Are you ok with a PowerShell solution?

Answer (score 2):

The trick here is that you should know the GUID of the inbuilt field whose display name you want to change. The GUIDs of such fields can be found in fieldswss.xml file located at 14\Template\Feature\fields folder.
So if you are creating a list without inheriting it from some content type, you will need to add a `Field` tag e.g;

```
<Field Type="Text" DisplayName="New Title Name" ID="{fa564e0f-0c70-4ab9-b863-0177e6ddd247}" Name="Title"/>
```

However, if you are inheriting from a content type you need to use `FieldRef` and also `Inherits` attribute of `ContentType` tag needs to be set to False in case of SharePoint 2010

```
<FieldRef Type="Text" DisplayName="New Title Name" ID="{fa564e0f-0c70-4ab9-b863-0177e6ddd247}" Name="Title"/>
```

[SharePoint: Change default field names in child content types](http://sharepointnadeem.blogspot.in/2011/06/change-default-field-names-in-child.html)

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you are doing this in Visual Studio.

The key to the blog is that Title actually has several hidden fields that are computed and those will also need to be changed.  Good luck!